# SQL Server: only return records where non unique return per multiple events w/ some duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to make a query in SQL Server.
The criteria that need to be met are:

1) There needs to be multiple duplicate records on col 1 and 3 (ex col 1 = A and col 3 = X three times)

2) only return said records when col 2 has more than one value over the multiple events (ex on col 1 and col 3, A and X have col 2 = 1 and 2)

In plainish speak...

Select all 
Where col 1, col 3 > 1

But col 2 can't be repeated
Unless there are already different values, then return the remainder of the values as long as they equal one of the different values

My problem is that I have not been unable to get rid of situations like where col 1 = E in the below example.

Example:

```
col 1 | col 2 | col 3
A     | 1     | Y
A     | 1     | X
A     | 2     | X
A     | 2     | X
B     | 1     | X
B     | 1     | Y
C     | 1     | X
C     | 2     | Y
D     | 1     | Y
D     | 2     | Y
E     | 1     | X
E     | 1     | X
F     | 1     | X
```

Desired Results:

```
col 1 | col 2 | col 3
A     | 1     | X
A     | 2     | X
A     | 2     | X
D     | 1     | Y
D     | 2     | Y
```

(edit: switched row to col, updated title)

Comment: I think you might need to change Row for Column in your question - it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT test.COL1,test.COL2,test.COL3 FROM test,
(   SELECT COL1,COL3 FROM test 
    GROUP BY COL1,COL3 
    HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT COL2)>=2
) table2
WHERE test.COL1=table2.COL1 AND test.COL3=table2.COL3
```

look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ba37/4/0